# How to use palaver on ubuntu 13.04 32bit?

Tags: 13.04, speech-recognition

I tried a lot to install palaver speech recognition software. But I have failed many a time. But eventually I installed it. However, I cannot use it! That's the problem. Tell me what to do?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to use it? Any message box showing any error? Please elaborate.

Comment: There's no message shown.But a mic icon shows on the unity panel.When I tried to speak it does not works.

Answer (score 1):

Could be that you have not pressed the shorcut again? Remember, you press, for instance, "Ctrl+L" to trigger the microphone, and again "Ctrl+L" to stop it)

Comment: I know that.But that shortcut isn't working.